# How effective is getting subset of document in MongoDB?

Tags: performance, mongodb

If we have a collection `photos` and each entry is a large document which contains all the information about photo including views details and detailed upvotes/downvotes.

```
{
_id:ObjectId('...'),
title:'...',
location:'...',
views:[
    {...},
    {...},
    ...
    ],
upvotes:[
    {...},
    {...},
    ...
    ],
downvotes:[
    {...},
    {...},
    ...
    ],
}
```

Which query would work faster and be more effective (memory, CPU usage):

```
db.photos.find().limit(100)
```

OR

```
db.photos.find({}, {views:0,upvotes:0,downvotes:0}).limit(100)
```

?

Comment: Omitting the extra data most likely if you don't need it because it wont need to be paged in, not only that but it won't need to go over the wire which means the batch size of a cursor can be bigger sending more data at once over the wire creating less traffic on the network

Comment: @Sammaye Yes, but someone told me that whenever you do request like second one it first fetches all the information about results, and only then runs mapReduce on results. Which means 1) Request like that will take longer time and 2) Will require more memory since all results will be first loaded completely.

Comment: second will be slowly because you use projection. it's more cpu usage operation.

Comment: AN MR is never run unless you specify an MR to be run, otherwise this query is done within the C++ code of MongoDB, MR runs within the JS engine which is a completely different thing.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry, thanks. This is the kind of answer i was looking for. So performance wise would you suggest to use first query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could it do yourself. just add `explain()` at the end of query.

for example:

```
db.photos.find().limit(100).explain()


{
  "cursor" : "<Cursor Type and Index>",
  "isMultiKey" : <boolean>,
  "n" : <num>,
  "nscannedObjects" : <num>,
  "nscanned" : <num>,
  "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : <num>,
  "nscannedAllPlans" : <num>,
  "scanAndOrder" : <boolean>,
  "indexOnly" : <boolean>,
  "nYields" : <num>,
  "nChunkSkips" : <num>,
  "millis" : <num>,
  "indexBounds" : { <index bounds> },
  "allPlans" : [
                 { "cursor" : "<Cursor Type and Index>",
                   "n" : <num>,
                   "nscannedObjects" : <num>,
                   "nscanned" : <num>,
                   "indexBounds" : { <index bounds> }
                 },
                  ...
               ],
  "oldPlan" : {
                "cursor" : "<Cursor Type and Index>",
                "indexBounds" : { <index bounds> }
              }
  "server" : "<host:port>",
}
```

**mills param is what you want**

If you want to see cpu usage just add `--cpu`  key in launch `mongod` script.

```
--cpu
Forces mongod to report the percentage of CPU time in write lock. mongod generates output every four seconds. MongoDB writes this data to standard output or the logfile if using the logpath option.
```

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/explain/

**You could provide `hint()` to mongo for `projection()` smth like this:**

we have simple collection:

```
> db.performance.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("50d2e4c08861fdb7e1c601ea"),
        "a" : 1,
        "b" : 1,
        "c" : 1,
        "d" : 1
}
```

Which consist of 23 elements:

```
> db.performance.count()
23
```

Now we can create compound index:

```
> db.performance.ensureIndex({'c':1, 'd':1})
```

And provide mongo a hint to use index for projection.

```
> db.performance.find({'a':1}, {'c':1, 'd':1}).hint({'c':1, 'd':1}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BtreeCursor c_1_d_1",
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "n" : 1,
        "nscannedObjects" : 23,
        "nscanned" : 23,
        "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 23,
        "nscannedAllPlans" : 23,
        "scanAndOrder" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "millis" : 0,
        "indexBounds" : {
                "c" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ],
                "d" : [
                        [
                                {
                                        "$minElement" : 1
                                },
                                {
                                        "$maxElement" : 1
                                }
                        ]
                ]
        },
        "server" : ""
}
>
```

Comment: Great, but what about CPU and memory utilization? Is there a way to see how it changes?

Comment: Thanks. This is the kind of answer i was looking for. So performance wise would you suggest to use first query?

Comment: it's depends from many factors. What kind of indexes do you have in collection?

Comment: add `explain()` output from both queries.

Comment: The query has no condition as such indexes dont matter here

Comment: if `SO` has compound indexes `{views:0,upvotes:0,downvotes:0}` mongo can use it for projection.

Comment: Have you got an official source to prove that? I mean how useful is an index for projection? A index is only useful for finding the document not projecting it. Using an index here would make projection extremely resource intensive and inefficient

Comment: That's because you used hint, it doesn't mean it actually used the index, it just loaded it and used up extra resources for no reason; check my edit

Comment: @AlexKey Also as you can see by my edit explain is not bery good at measuring the cost of projection

Comment: @Sammaye If you have a covered index, where the values of all required fields are indexed, mongo won't need to load the documents, it can get the query results from the index alone. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/indexes/#create-indexes-that-support-covered-queries

Comment: @chrisbunney Projection occurs after getting the results, if covered index would work in this case then my edit below would include an index. MongoDBs optimiser knows about this stuff.

Comment: The fact that covered indexes work suggests that projection doesn't necessarily happen after getting the results, since covered indexes avoid reading the entire document from the database. You asked for an official source about using indexes with projection, which was my main reason for commenting with the link

Comment: @chrisbunney Check my edit, a covered index will not work here...I am unsure what makes you think it is. A covered index is just a condition (including the sort) which includes all fields present in the index, you can't use an index on a full table scan.

Answer (score 5):

There are actually two sides to this story, the application and the server.

In the application the second will be way faster. The application will not have to de-serialise the BSON document (CPU intensive) and then store the hash (memory intensive) of unneeded data.

On the server MongoDB can send more data down the wire allowing more iterations per cursor before you have to do a `getMore` op allowing you to increase performance on that front. Not only that but you are, of course, sending less data. A `getMore` operation is actually resource intensive in itself for both memory and CPU so that's a saver.

As for within the server itself there is a small cost for the projection however it will be smaller than the cost of bringing it all over.

#### Edit

As others have said, MongoDB does actually use projection to just manipulate the result set as such you will have the same working set between the two queries.

#### Edit

This is results of index usage on projection:

```
> db.g.insert({a:1,b:1,c:1,d:1})
> db.g.ensureIndex({ a:1,b:1,c:1 })
> db.g.find({}, {a:0,b:0,c:0}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "nscanned" : 3,
        "nscannedObjects" : 3,
        "n" : 3,
        "millis" : 0,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {

        }
}
> db.g.find({}, {a:1,b:1,c:1}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "nscanned" : 3,
        "nscannedObjects" : 3,
        "n" : 3,
        "millis" : 0,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {

        }
}
```

This is also the results of not using projection:

```
> db.g.find({}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "nscanned" : 3,
        "nscannedObjects" : 3,
        "n" : 3,
        "millis" : 0,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {

        }
}
```

As you can see the `milis` denoting time spent on the document was actually the same between both: `0`. So explain is not a good way of measureing this.

#### Another Edit

Excluding _id does not make a covered index be applied:

```
> db.g.find({}, {a:1,b:1,c:1,_id:0}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "nscanned" : 3,
        "nscannedObjects" : 3,
        "n" : 3,
        "millis" : 0,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {

        }
}
```

#### Yet another edit

And with 300K rows:

```
> db.g.find({}, {a:1,b:1,c:1}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "nscanned" : 300003,
        "nscannedObjects" : 300003,
        "n" : 300003,
        "millis" : 95,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {

        }
}

> db.g.find({}).explain()
{
        "cursor" : "BasicCursor",
        "nscanned" : 300003,
        "nscannedObjects" : 300003,
        "n" : 300003,
        "millis" : 85,
        "nYields" : 0,
        "nChunkSkips" : 0,
        "isMultiKey" : false,
        "indexOnly" : false,
        "indexBounds" : {

        }
}
```

So it is true that projection is more costly on a huge result set but remeber that is projection on 300K rows...I mean WTF? Who is, in their right mind, going to do that? So this part of the argument doesn't really exist. Either way the difference is like 10 ms on my hardware, nearly only 1/10th of your query as such projection is not your problem here.

I should also note that the `--cpu` flag will not give you what you want, for starters it actually concerns itself with write lock and second your doing a read.

Comment: Why do you think using `hint()` for projection is overhead for resources?

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry Because `hint()` forces an index to be loaded even if it cannot be used for the query. In other words you loaded an index into your working set for a query that cannot use it for a full table scan.

Comment: To use a covered index, you'd need to explicitly exclude the _id field as well. E.g. `db.g.find({}, {a:1,b:1,c:1,_id:0})` because the _id field is normally always included. As an aside, I don't think you can draw any meaningful conclusions about performance from comparing queries on a collection with only 3 documents. A few hundred thousand documents is much more likely to expose performance differences